# Vue:js Vuex store is updated but component is not updating in the component panel

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Component is not updating even though vuex store is updated, tried by using to computed.

**store.js**

```
 const actions = {
      addToInProgress: ({ commit, state }, incidentId) => {
        commit(Type.ADD_TO_PROGRESS, incidentId);
      },
  };

 const mutations = {    
     [Type.ADD_TO_PROGRESS]: (state, incidentId) => {
        const someArray = [...state.incidentArray];
        console.log("incidentId: to be progressed from mutation", incidentId);
        const incidentObj = someArray.find(i => i._id === incidentId);
        // state.incidentArray.filter(i => i.props.status === "new");

        incidentObj.props.status = "inProgress";
        console.log("incidentObj found to be in progress:", incidentObj, "and incident arrray:", someArray);
        Object.assign(state, { incidentArray: someArray });
    },
 };

const getters = {
    incidentsNew: (state) => { return state.incidentArray.filter(i => i.props.status === "new"); },
    incidentsInProgress: (state) => { return state.incidentArray.filter(i => i.props.status === "inProgress"); },
    incidentsResolved: (state) => { return state.incidentArray.filter(i => i.props.status === "resolved"); },
    incidentTypeConfig: (state) => { return state.incidentTypeConfig; }
};
```

**component.js**

```
//  here I am using computed but also incidents is not updating in the component
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        incidentsPending: "incident/incidentsNew",
        incidentsInProgress: "incident/incidentsInProgress",
        incidentsResolved: "incident/incidentsResolved"

    }),
```

Comment: can you show your getters?

Comment: here are my  /* GETTERS */

    const getters = {
    incidentsNew: (state) => {
        return state.incidentArray.filter(i => i.props.status === "new");
    },

    incidentsInProgress: (state) => {
        return state.incidentArray.filter(i => i.props.status === "inProgress");
    },

       incidentTypeConfig: (state) => {
        return state.incidentTypeConfig;
    }
};

Comment: The incidents should be updated form new to inprogress

Comment: are you using Vuex modules? or a single store object? it looks like you are trying to map getters from the `incident` module, can you update your question with the store definition